# Iframe content not loading in react-native-webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

In my application, users can redirect to app website using react-native-webview. Here iframe content is not loading through my app but works fine while using a mobile browser. It shows some authentication errors:
[image]

But I  didn’t get the proper cause of this issue. I tried by adding

```
allowFileAccess={true},
scalesPageToFit={true},
sharedCookiesEnabled={true},
javaScriptEnabled={true},
useWebKit={true},
originWhitelist={['*']},
DomStorageEnabled={true},
userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_2_1)  AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2 Safari/605.1.15"
```

But nothing solves my issue.